# Vim netrw automatically buffer switching bug

Tags: vim, netrw

I have a bug with navigation: sometimes Netrw switching me onto another buffers. I'm opening 2 buffers. Now I'm on the left. Type ":e /home/user". Then press "-" (go to the parent directory). Oops! Netrw switching me onto the right panel! :-( What is it?
It happens periodically. Not every time.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to reproduce this with the latest development version of *netrw* from [Dr Chip's Vim Page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW); the author frequently releases updates there.

If you still see the problem with it, try to work out the minimal steps to reproduce the bug (no `.vimrc`, no other plugins, simple directory structure, etc.), and report this to the author (the email address can be found in the help and plugin scripts).

Remember that Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker; the plugin author is in the best position to help you!